# Can we add a user to sharepoint database directly without creating user from office 365 using rest api?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to create some dummy user directly into sharepoint user database without creating user from office 365 using rest api

Answer (score 0):

It's restricted to do that, kindly check that link 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841057/support-for-changes-to-the-databases-that-are-used-by-office-server-pr

however you can create the user programmatically, kindly check that question

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91607/how-programmatically-create-a-new-user-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Actually I want to create user directly in SP.UserProfile

Answer (score 0):

If you use SharePoint Online, the users store in Azure AD and SharePoint get the users from the Azure AD using User Profile Service, if you want to add user to Azure AD, the following PowerShell for your reference.

```
$PasswordProfile=New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
$PasswordProfile.Password="<user account password>"
New-AzureADUser -DisplayName "<display name>" -GivenName "<first name>" -SurName "<last name>" -UserPrincipalName <sign-in name> -UsageLocation <ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code> -MailNickName <mailbox name> -PasswordProfile $PasswordProfile -AccountEnabled $true
```

Refer to: [Create user accounts with Office 365 PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/create-user-accounts-with-office-365-powershell)

If you use SharePoint 2013 on-premise, the SharePoint users also get from AD using User Profile Service. Refer to the article here: [Add User Profiles in SharePoint 2013 using PowerShell Script](https://manasbhardwaj.net/add-user-profiles-sharepoint-2013-using-powershell-script/)